# NSManagedObject collection properties become nil after a while

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmanagedobject

I'm working in a subclass of `NSViewController` where in `viewDidLoad` I fetch my entities from `CoreData` as below:

```
let delegate = AppDelegate.init()
let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetch = PicPathEntity.entityFetchRequest()

var tempEntities: [PicPathEntity] = []
context.performAndWait {
    tempEntities = try! fetch.execute()
}
entities = tempEntities
```

Then during the `itemForRepresentedObjectAt` function, it appears that the count of entities is the same, but the property values have become `nil`/empty.

I did some searching and found similar problems with no clear answers (at least not for `Swift`)

I can't seem to find information on how to properly fetch and retain the data in my entities variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this after reading the how the relationship between objects and context work.

Turns out all I needed to make this work, was make the context into a property of the `ViewController` instead of a local variable of `viewDidLoad`.

```
var entities: [PicPathEntity] = []
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let delegate = AppDelegate.init()
    context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetch = PicPathEntity.entityFetchRequest()
    context.performAndWait {
        entities = try! fetch.execute()
    }
}
```

Due to helpful comments to this answer, I have now updated the code to:

```
var entities: [PicPathEntity] = []
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let delegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetch = PicPathEntity.entityFetchRequest()
    context.perform {
        self.entities = try! fetch.execute()
        self.picFinderEntityCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    configureCollectionView()
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `AppDelegate.init()` returns **not** the application delegate class specified in the storyboard. It's a brand new instance. And a `fetch` is synchronous anyway.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by this. It refers to the AppDelegate class defined in my project. Is there something else I should be aware of or use a different way to initialize the delegate for whatever purpose?

Comment: If you are using storyboard it does **not** refer to the `AppDelegate` instance which is connected to the application delegate. You get the **real** reference with `let delegate = UIAppplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`

Comment: Can you expand on  why would that be beneficial and what your comment regarding the fetch being synchronous mean in context of my code and intent? Thanks in advance for the real reference.

Comment: 1) If you create new instances of AppDelegate you get different `ManagedObjectContext`s which can cause problems. 2) The `performAndWait` block is pointless because the fetch is synchronous, that means it waits anyway.